# Search bar overlaps with status bar on iOS 11

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, ios11

I am using a UISearchController and a UISearchResultsController to implement search functionality.

MySearchResultsController implements UISearchResultsUpdating and UISearchBarDelegate:

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = [];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
}
```

I display the searchbar in the tableHeader like this in MyTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self.searchResultsController;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self.searchResultsController;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[NSLocalizedString(@"SEARCH_SCOPE_TEMPERATURES", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"SEARCH_SCOPE_KNOWHOW", nil)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

This worked perfectly before, but under iOS 11 the search bar overlaps with the status bar as soon as I tap into it (see screenshots). I tried lots of different things to get it to display correctly but haven't found a solution yet.

[image]

Comment: I just found out, that this doesn't happen when I remove the scope button titles (which I don't want to do…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem was that the presenting view Controller also sets

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = [];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
}
```

I have to do this because the table view does not actually extend all the way to the top.

I solved this like that in my presenting view Controller:

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        //NSLog(@"iOS 11.0");
    } else {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        //NSLog(@"iOS < 11.0");
    }
}
```

Seems to be an iOS 11 bug, or at least an odd behavior…

Comment: This is definitely a bug, although I found I did not have to provide the if statement given in the answer marked as correct.  Simply adding the assignment statement fixed all situations where the bug was occurring (all versions from 8.2 to 10.3.1) and did not alter situations where things were displaying fine (versions including and after 11.0).

Answer (score 1):

This is what Worked for me:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // to fix the Status Bar Issue:
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            definesPresentationContext = true
        }
       // You'll also need this properties on your Search Bar:
        searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation is what i was looking for!

Comment: Hiding the navigation bar prevents the elegant shifting up animation of search bar. This might solve the overlapping issue as there is no more shifting up animation but this might not be what everyone wants. I personally like the shifting up animation but for this bug in iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by subclassing UISearchController. My answer is in Swift but maybe the principles works with ojective-c as well. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339336/8639272